# sqlservr.exe's virtual size is big – should I worry?

Tags: windows, memory, sql-server

[image: Process explorer on system, sorted: Virtual size]

1. Is this normal? Does the large virtual size matter on `sqlservr.exe` for
   the performance of other apps? It seems to happen any time I use Firefox and iTunes. (    Also running is League of Legends)
2. Can I test if this is stemming from either iTunes or Firefox in Process Explorer?
3. Does "virtual size" mean adding up the total requested memory (if libraries were not shared), or something else?

Note that I'm not running an SQL server, and Firefox uses SQLite 3, so I'm not sure if it even uses `sqlservr.exe`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nor Firefox or itunes are using SQL Server, that's for sure. And SQL server use free memory for cache, you don't have to worry that is a normal behavior.

More on this link:

http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2006/07/memory-use-in-sql-server.html